# python replace ︰ (unicode - 0xFE30) with : (unicode - 0x3a) in python (programmatically, rather than replace it using dictionary mapping)

Tags: python-3.x, string, text, nlp, data-cleaning

I am cleaning text in python, and I want to replace ︰ (unicode - 0xFE30) with : (unicode - 0x3a) in python automatically (programmatically, rather than replace it using dictionary mapping), since that affects the further results in text analysis

find some similarity between the above 2 symbols, could not find any.

unicodedata, the text is in chinese

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Dictionary mapping in a program is "programmatically". And dot data cleaning you should do a lot of such heuristic/manual conversions. The main problem: U+FE30 can be normalized (compatibility) with U+2025 `‥`, so not U+003A. Note 2025 is normalized again with two dots.

Comment: Sorry, I think the word I was looking for was automatic, instead of programmatically.